# Extract JSON Objects from HTML text file

Tags: javascript, json

I have objects I'm trying to extract from a HTML file.

```
<h1> heading</h1>
<p> dsfhklsd sdlfjklsdj ljsdkflj</p>
{"data" : {"here" : "test"} }
<h2> heading</h2>
<p> dsfhklsd sdlfjklsdj ljsdkflj</p>
<p> dsfhklsd sdlfjklsdj ljsdkflj</p>
{"data2" : {"here" : "test"} }
```

How would I go about extracting the Objects so I can then parse them with JSON.parse() and use them in my JS code?

Essentially stripping anything that is not an object from the text / html file.

```
{"data" : {"here" : "test"} }
{"data2" : {"here" : "test"} }
```

Comment: First question is what source would mix json as text nodes with html like that? Would make more sense if it was mixed into data attributes or `<code>` or `<pre>` tags but not the way it is shown

Answer (score 4):

You can loop over the nodes and select the text nodes.

```js
var objs = Array.from(document.body.childNodes) // select all the nodes
  .filter( // pick out just the lines we want
    node => 
      node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE &&  // text node
      node.nodeValue.trim().length  // get rid of line feeds
  ).map(node =>
    JSON.parse(node.nodeValue.trim())) // convert to object

console.log(objs)
```

```html
<h1> heading</h1>
<p> dsfhklsd sdlfjklsdj ljsdkflj</p>
{"data" : {"here" : "test"} }
<h2> heading</h2>
<p> dsfhklsd sdlfjklsdj ljsdkflj</p>
<p> dsfhklsd sdlfjklsdj ljsdkflj</p>
{"data2" : {"here" : "test"} }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your source is being processed by JavaScript as a string, I would use a Regex delete all the html elements (assuming that the JSON you want isn't wrapped in an html element, like in your example) or parse everything between the curly brackets.